# Play m3u8 file via mplayer having encrypted m4s contents

Tags: video, openssl, mplayer, decrypt

I have init.mp4, playlist.m3u8 and multiple .m4s files which are encrypted. When I try playing the video via MPlayer playlist.m3u8, it gives error like:

```
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing playlist.m3u8.
libavformat version 57.83.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7fa4c021c2a0]Opening 'init.mp4' for reading
Could not read complete segment.
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7fa4c021c2a0]Opening 'http://107.108.87.159/openssl+ffmpeg/enc.key' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7fa4c021c2a0]Opening 'crypto:playlist0.m4s' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7fa4c021c2a0]No longer receiving playlist 0
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7fa4c021c2a0]Now receiving playlist 0, segment 0
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7fa4c021c2a0]Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 320x240): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
LAVF: Program 0
VIDEO:  [H264]  320x240  24bpp  12800.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 57.107.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Load subtitles in ./
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
V:   0.0   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0

Exiting... (End of file)
```

My two major doubts:

1. Does mplayer decrypt the encrypted content by itself or not?
2. Or first do I need to decrypt it independently via OpenSSL, then try playing it with MPlayer?

Comment: Have you got the correct decryptor?

Comment: I did not understand. Kindly elaborate. I think mplayer should decrypt right?

Comment: My two major doubts:                                                      
1. Does mplayer decrypt the encryted content by itself or not?                                                                                  
2.Or first I need to decrypt it independently via openssl then try playing with mplayer?